# Powershell Scan folder for certain file name and Write to a log file and email

Tags: email, powershell, vbscript, windows-server-2008, directory

We have Drop-box running in the office and sometime there are conflicted files created

it will save two versions of the file and label one a "conflicted copy"

This pisses off my bosses a lot

Iam thinking about using task scheduler to run the script every 6 hours

I need to Scan a folder With the sub-folder for the file name "conflicted copy" and if there are any files present with this name to write to a log file and email the NOC team

File server Details
OS : Windows Server 2008 Enterprise

Directory - E:\Dropbox

I tinkered around with Filesystemwatcher didn't get it to work with my modifications so im looking for some help from you guys to shed some light on this

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Show us the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$conflicted = Get-ChildItem E:\Dropbox -Recurse -Filter "*conflicted copy*" | Foreach-Object {$_.FullName}

if($conflicted)
{
    $body = $conflicted | Out-String
    Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer srv1 -From you@domain.com -To boss@domain.com -Subject 'conflicted copy files' -Body $body
}
```

Comment: hey thanks That works. Thanks a lot man

I modified a bit like this

`code`
Out-File -filepath "C:\scripts\Logfile.txt"  -append -InputObject "The conflicted files $conflicted"
`code`


For the log file how can i format the output?
Because currently it just writes in on the same line

Comment: Try this in the inside the IF statement: $conflicted | foreach { "The conflicted file $_"  | Out-File "C:\scripts\Logfile.txt" -Append}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14337384/powershell-combining-2-different-scripts-and-send-notification-email

Hey dude Can you Help out on this